# Server connection dropped while downloading large files(600Mb)from sftp using pysftp library in python

Tags: python, pysftp

I have a python script which downloads some files from `sftp` server. But getting server connection dropped error after some time.

++++Error+++

> File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 188, in _read_all
>       raise EOFError()
>   EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 845, in _read_response
>       raise SSHException("Server connection dropped: {}".format(e))
>   paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server connection dropped:

+++++++

```
artifact = self.artifact_folder + filename
self.session.get(filename, artifact)
```

Comment: Are you able to download the file without using `pysftp` ?

Comment: This might be helpful [Connection fails for Windows SFTP Host and Big Files > 100M](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/issues/93/connection-fails-for-windows-sftp-host-and)

Comment: @CodeIt yes, able to download the file without pysftp

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: It didnt resolve my issue. I need to get it working using pysftp.

Comment: Did you check server-side log files? + Does the connection drop after specific time? Or is it random?